# Loop through every image in a server-side folder

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I have a webpage where I want to load a gallery of images however, there are many images and they will be changing periodically so I do not want to have to manually write every image tag. Is there a way to have a js script go through the folder and append the images to the body of my site? 
**Note**: I cannot use PHP as I am running this on a Github pages and they allow only static pages and PHP isn't static

Comment: If you wish to do anything on server side, how can a client side script(static) can do it?

Comment: @crack_iT Is it entirely impossible to accomplish something like this with these restrictions? If so, what would be a possible alternative to trying to solve it in this way

Comment: Just think again that a code running in your browser(client side), there  is no way it can do anything on server side. All it can do is call another code(service) that run on server.
You can use any other server side language, if not wish to use php.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way i can think of is to put images with preformated names like, image1, image2, image3
Then in javascript, loop untill you get 404 for next image

```
var i=1;
while(true) {
var path="image" +i;
//Check if its not 404, then embedd image to html and continue, otherwise break loop
}
```